# Check if entry exists before committing the transaction Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have a transaction and inside it, I do the following :

1. BeginTransaction
2. Adding a test entry in database

   ```
   var test_data = UnitOfWork.Tests.AddTest(scenario.FirstOrDefault(), fixture_data);
   ```
3. Adding a step entry in the database and Saving The changes
4. Check if the test exists in the database

   ```
   var test_scenario = StContext.Tests.FirstOrDefault(Test => Test.Title == test.Title);
   ```
5. Do more stuff and then commit Transaction.

The problem is that when checking if the test exists in the database(even if is not yet committed to database) it returns true because I used `SaveChanges()` method when adding the step

Is there a way to check if an entry exists in a table in the same transaction after adding the entry, saving the changes, but before committing the transaction?

Somehow is returning the entry from memory

Comment: Why not checking for presence first and then inserting it?

Comment: You're also right, but for my scenario is not really perfect, because I want that Test to be added in a Session table no matter what, then save the session, then insert other properties like Result,Steps,Tags..., (but only if the entry in the database does not exist-> that's why this check for test after inserting), then commit

Comment: Ok, so you still can check for presence before inserting and keep that value(lets call it IsPresent). Then insert your test object no matter what. After that you still can use your 'IsPresent' value for further checking

Comment: Yo're right, I can use that(I will use that). I was more curios if there is a way to get the entry from the database itself(instead of entity context memory, before committing/pushing the transaction )

Comment: You see inserting data x in the table. You have not committed the transaction and you suspect that the same data x is already there. In what use case is this possible?